# Select dropdown displaying over the select div

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

The select dropdown is displaying normally on Chrome, FF, starting from select div but it is displaying over the select div when it has dozens of options. How can I fix this?

```
<div id="select-o>
    <i class="ti-angle-down"></i>
      <select><option>....</options></select>
<div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you used any CSS?

Comment: Can I change it with css? It seems native to IE. I am using the select tag.